# Call a method accepting TX as a generic type from another method with Generic Type T having List(L), with the type of (L) in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, types, propertyinfo

I have a method(**methodA**) accepting T as a generic type and all classes (**C1,C2,**..) for T have a List parameter having different names and types (**L**).

```
public class C1{
    public List<L1> C1List{get;set;}=new List<L1>();
}

public class C2{
    public List<L2> C2List {get;set;}=new List<L2>();
}
```

I want to call another method (**methodB**) accepting **TX** as a generic type from **methodA** and **methodB** should be called with the type of the List (**L**).

My attempt to fix the problem was incomplete as I couldn't find a way to set the **TypeOfPi**.

```
public T methodA<T>(){
    var r= Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    var pi= r.GetType().GetProperties().First(p => p.PropertyType.Name == "List`1");

    pi.SetValue(r,methodB<TypeOfPi>());

    return r;
}

public List<TX> methodB<TX>(){
    var r=new List<TX>();
    .
    .
    return r;
}
```

Is there a way to set **TypeOfPi** or any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: You need to fix code samples. What is `myReturn`? `public C1 {` is it class? `=new C1List();` not valid C# syntax.

Comment: I have fixed code samples. C1,C2 are classes. Each has a List of different types.

Comment: I can solve my problem if I send type of List as T2 and modify methodA<T,T2> and call methodB<T2>. But if I do so, even if the type of the List can be extracted from T, I have to send the type of the List each time which seems to me as redundency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code in `methodA` you need to use reflection to call `methodB`:

```
public T methodA<T>()
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    var listProperty = instance.GetType().GetProperties().First(p => p.PropertyType.Name == "List`1");
    
    var listGenericArgType = listProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    
    var methodB = this.GetType().GetMethod("methodB").MakeGenericMethod(listGenericArgType);
    var methodBResult = methodB.Invoke(this, null);
     
    listProperty.SetValue(instance, methodBResult);

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: listProperty.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First() raises an error since listProperty.GetType().GetGenericArguments() returns 0 records.

Comment: @aza, you're right, it should be `var listGenericArgType = listProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();`, edited my answer